# Javascript. Mostrar datos de un campo select, tendria que hacerlo con ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formularios, select

que tal?.. Soy un poco nuevo con javascript y queria consutar algo:
Tengo un formulario que ademas de varios campos tiene un campo select. Este campo select al desplegar la lista muestra el nombre de registros que estan en una base de datos.

Lo que quisiera hacer es, al seleccionar uno, obtener los demas campos que tiene ese registro, por ejemplo:
El campo select muestra una lista desplegable de nombres de personas (donde nombre es solo un campo del registro persona que ademas puede tener apellido y edad). Entonces al seleccionar una opcion quiero saber como puedo hacer para tomar el apellido y edad para luego mostrarlo en pantalla.

Esto tendria que hacerlo con AJAX?, Jquery creo que no me serviria porque solo podria obtener el valor de ese select verdad?

No busco que me pasen codigo porque quiero intentar a ver si puedo hacerlo por mi cuenta, me gustaria por favor si me podrian guiar mas o menos como serian los pasos que tendria que seguir.. Gracias desde ya!

Comment: Hola Enzzo, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, te cuento que este tipo de preguntas podrías hacerlas mejor en el [chat] ya que es una pregunta demasiado amplia, pero tomando en cuenta tu necesidad te informo que si debes usar ajax para generar una comunicación asíncrona con el servidor y mostrar los datos que requieres, saludos !

Comment: Hola Camilo, gracias por tu respuesta y recomendaciones, voy a hacer el recorrido asi voy aprendiendo mas, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

sí podés usar jQuery que, fijate `$.ajax` que hace muy facil hacer llamadas con ajax.

El registro que está en la base de datos debe tener una clave primaria (un id).

Cuando generas el `select`, también generas los `option` con los nombres, bueno en cada `option` incluye como `value` el id del registro.

De esa forma podes mandar ese valor en el `ajax` para recuperar el resto de los datos de ese registro.

Para el ida y vuelta de los datos entre el browser y el servidor podes usar json.

Comment: Buenisimo Juan ,gracias, me voy a fijar entonces la documentacion de $.ajax